# Add-ADGroupMember can't find an object with identity

Tags: powershell, active-directory, activedirectorymembership

I am having trouble trying to solve a simple issue. My script works up to the point of adding the ADComputer to the AD Security Group. I have even tried adjusting the `Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $groupName -Members $NameofRandomComputer -verbose` but it doesn't work.

I know for a fact that the script does create the groups, it does read the OUs for the computer names and it does randomize successfully. I can even see it trying to add the computers but it fails to find the computer name, which makes no sense. What gives?

> Error: Cannot find an object with identity: MissouriWorkstation001 under "DC=domain,DC=com"

```
$logfile = "results-$((Get-Date).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy_hhmmtt')).log"

Get-Date | Out-File $logfile

$groupnameprefix = 'Test_Create_AD_Group'
$organizationalunitpath = 'OU=Systems,OU=Corp,DC=domain,DC=com'
$grouporganizationalunitpath = 'OU=Groups,OU=Corp,DC=domain,DC=com'
$NumberofComputersPerGroup = '10'
# This is a list of computer names that will be used to generate group names
$Patch_Groups = @(
    '_Group_1',
    '_Group_2',
    '_Group_3',
    '_Group_4'
)

# Get all computers from the specified organizational unit
$computers = $organizationalunitpath |
    ForEach-Object { Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase $_ } |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name -Verbose

# Create the new group
foreach ($Patch_Group in $Patch_Groups) {
    # Generate the group name by concatenating the prefix and the Patch Group name with spaces removed
    $groupname = $groupnameprefix + $Patch_Group.Replace(' ', '')
    # Create the group using the generated name and the specified organizational unit path
    New-ADGroup -Name $groupName -path $grouporganizationalunitpath -GroupScope Global -verbose

    # Randomly select the specified number of computers and add them to the group
    $randomComputers = $computers | Get-Random -Count $NumberofComputersPerGroup -Verbose
    foreach ($NameofRandomComputer in $randomComputers) {
        try {
            Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $groupName -Members $NameofRandomComputer -verbose
        }
        catch {
            $message = ' A problem occurred trying to add Member '
            $message | Out-File $logfile -Append
            Write-Warning $message
            Write-Warning $_.Exception.Message
            $_.Exception.Message | Out-File $logfile -Append
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also using the CanonicalName should not be an issue, as I did this before using this method here:
Get-CMDevice -CollectionName "Home Worker Subnet" | 
    Select -ExpandProperty Name | 
        ForEach-Object{ Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "SCCM_Home_Worker_Subnet" -Members $_$ }

Comment: I think that works because it's remaining within the pipeline, so possibly still handling the original object down the line, unlike when you assign it to a variable where you're assigning that one property to a variable with no connection to the original object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue stems from the line :

```
# Get all computers from the specified organizational unit
$computers = $organizationalunitpath | ForEach-Object {Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase $_} | Select -ExpandProperty Name -verbose
```

however if you check the syntax for Add-ADGroupMember

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/add-adgroupmember?view=windowsserver2022-ps

you'll see that the expected values for -members are either Distinguished name, GUID (objectGUID), Security identifier (objectSid) or SAM account name (sAMAccountName), not Name.

So because you specifically selected Name from Get-ADComputer rather than just getting the entire object, it's unable to find the Computer with the supplied value. I'd suggest changing the first line to :

```
$computers = $organizationalunitpath | ForEach-Object {Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase $_}
```

and then within the for loop leave the Get-ADGroupMember line as :

```
try { Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $groupName -Members $NameofRandomComputer -verbose   }
```

That way you simply pass the entire Computer object via $NameOfRandomComputer to Add-ADGroupMember rather than picking out a single property... in this case the wrong property. I'd argue the only time you need to specifically retrieve the individual property is if you're going to display/record that text somewhere, in which case you can use $NameofRandomComputer.name to reference that property, and the rest of the time let Powershell continue working with complete objects as designed.

Comment: You can remove the "I think.." part of your answer, you're absolutely correct, the problem with OP's code is expanding the `.Name` property of the computer objects when `-Members` only accepts an ADPrincipal as argument.

Comment: That was it. It works now. Thanks. How would I ensure, my verbose or log shows the computer names being added in? at the Try { ADD-ADgroupmember ?

Comment: @user3911968 that is unrelated to the original question, you should ask a new question for that.

Comment: @user3911968 as I menioned you can use .name, so :
$message = "A problem occurred trying to add Member $($NameofRandomComputer.name)"